# Running bash command with python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I have a command in my bash_profile such as `id=12345` which I defined the following alias

`alias obs="echo $id"` since the id will chance over time.

Now what I want to do is call this alias in my python script for different purposes. My default shell is bash so I have tried the following based on the suggestions on the web

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('obs', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', obs])

subprocess.Popen('obs', shell=True,executable='/bin/bash')

subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c','-i', obs])
```

However, none of them seems to work! What am I doing wrong!

Comment: Shell aliases are in interactive shell feature. You cannot access them from Python. You can access the environment variable (`id`), only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is not read by `Popen` and friends.

Environment variables are available for your script, though (via `os.environ`).

You can use `export` in your Bash shell to export a value as an environment variable, or use `env`:

```
export MY_SPECIAL_VALUE=12345
python -c "import os; print(os.environ['MY_SPECIAL_VALUE'])"
# or
env MY_SPECIAL_VALUE=12345 python -c "import os; print(os.environ['MY_SPECIAL_VALUE'])"
```

Comment: Or even without the `env` like this `MY_SPECIAL_VALUE=18 python ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure, that works in Bash, but `env` is portable.